# Timing programs in C

Tags: c, timing

I need to time my C program inside the program itself (as I am timing multiple subsections of the code and outputting their time).  It must be done with (at least) millisecond accuracy.  My understanding is that "time.h" functions only work to the second.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: Linux, but shouldn't it be possible to do this in a platform independent way, as the timing is done within the program itself.

Comment: Make a wrapper for the time function. Use `#if`s and/or `#ifdef`s to supply platform specific time functions. Do not supply a default implementation. That way your code doesn't even compile on platforms you don't know about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `clock()` from `<time.h>`:

> The clock() function returns an approximation of processor time used by the program.

You divide the return value by the macro `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to get a time amount in seconds, and if you wanted the time in milliseconds you could multiply the value by 1000, ie:

```
double get_time_as_ms(void) {
   return ((double)(clock() * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Or more accurately, have a start and end `clock_t` and then calculate the difference:

```
double duration_as_ms(clock_t start, clock_t end) {
    return ((double)(end - start) * 1000) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

}

clock_t start = clock(); /* start of program */
/* ... */
clock_t end = clock(); /* end of program */
/* ... */
printf("Duration: %fms\m", duration_as_ms(start, end));
```

**EDIT:** Just thought I'd add, a common value for `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is `1000000`, meaning that the value returned by `clock()` would be a one-hundred-thousandth of a second. Therefore it's accurate to one one-thousandth of a millisecond (a microsecond).

Comment: But you will loose the precision, isn't thats the first requirement in the question....

Comment: @havexz: The value returned by `clock()` should be more precise than milliseconds. On my machine, `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is defined as `1000000`, therefore it's accurate to one one-hundred-thousandth of a second. Which means it's accurate to one-thousandth of a millisecond.

Comment: got it...actually what you are saying in answer and the code snippet say different things. In answer you said divide first and multiply later and snippet is opposite...its my bad..its clear now

Comment: @havexz: Yeah I might not have worded it too well. I edited the wording after I posted it to try and make it reflect what I actually meant in the code, but it still probably isn't great. If you multiply the wrong way you *could* lose precision.

Comment: Does the OP really want CPU time, not wall-clock time? Also note that just because CLOCKS_PER_SECs is high doesn't mean there are that many significant digits.

Comment: I got some more info so thought to share, clock only tells you about CPU time not real time `http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/strftime.html` so if you looking for only cpu time its ok

Answer (score 2):

You may try the `gettimeofday` function the time has an accuracy of microseconds.

Comment: This will only work on platforms that implement `gettimeofday`. It's not standard libc. Also, while `timeval` has enough room to return microseconds, the actual resolution is platform-dependent.